# error 404 page not found opening 2fauth with traefik proxy

Tags: http-status-code-404, traefik

I use the Two-Factor Authentication from the github-project Bubka/2FAuth with Traefik as proxy. When I connect local to my host 192.168.1.80:8010, every thing is fine. When I connect via my external address https://2fauth.bla.com, i get always the error "404 page not found". My docker compose has this configuration:
version: "3.7"

services:

```
  2fauth:
    image: 2fauth/2fauth
    container_name: 2fauth
    volumes:
      - /docker-data/2fauth/data:/data
    ports:
      - 8010:8000/tcp
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.2fauth.rule=Host(`2fauth.bla.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.2fauth.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.2fauth.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
      - "traefik.http.services.2fauth.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
    restart: always

networks:
  default:
    name: webproxy
    external: true
```

When I try to change the ports from
ports:

```
  - 80:8000/tcp
Launching docker-compose up I get the error:
Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint 2fauth (1ec80300104fcefad34a5265cbcc0c17a781a2983b6379b4db3e162040d2840c): Bind for 0.0.0.0:80 failed: port is already allocated
```

Can you help me

Comment: I have understood, that the 2fauth service is listen on port 8000 and therefore I changed the last line of traefik configuration in "treafik.http.services.2fauth.loadbalancer.server.port=8000". Now I do not anymore receive the "page not found"-error, but I get a blank website. Why thät?